# ng-click on checkbox returns array

Tags: angularjs, scope, ng-class

I have a problem with my AngularJS Application, I try to call a function in my Controller but the parameter when I `console.log(id);` , id is an array...

## I Use `[ ]` instead of `{{ }}` because i'm working with TWIG

Angular Template (html source)

```
<div class="ext-[f.ext]" ng-repeat="f in files">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="select([f.id],'file')">
    <div>[f.name]</div>
</div>
```

Rendered by Angular

```
<div class="ext-html" ng-repeat="f in files">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="select(27,'file')">
    <div ng-binding">index.html</div>
</div>
```

My JS function

```
$scope.select = function (id ,type) {
    console.log(id); // Array
    console.log(type); // String (as expected)
}
```

console Output :

```
[28] app.js:74
file app.js:75
```

The problem is that I have this which works...

```
<div class="folder row" ng-repeat="f in folders" ng-click="getFolder([f.id])">
    <div class="col-md-12">[f.name]</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying an array as the parameter.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="select([f.id],'file')">
```

Should be

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="select(f.id,'file')">
```

You create arrays in javascript using the square brackets.

```
var array = [ 1, 2, 3, 4];
```

So you created an array with a single value in which was your id.

1. Even if you use the same syntax as an array for your bindings you don't need to use bindings in that context.
2. You shouldn't "override" a standard language construct to do something completely different as you might get unexpected behaviour
3. Proof http://plnkr.co/edit/4n2yg6QudzcFA5bazjZ3?p=preview

Comment: `[]` isn't binding syntax for angular it's `{{}}`, and you don't need to bind in an ng-click attribute because it's already expecting an expression. Did you try my suggested fix? You might be surprised.

Comment: Actually, I have made something which works fine.  
`<div class="folder" ng-repeat="f in folders" ng-click="getFolder([f.id])"></div>`

but this not

Comment: I don't know what twig is but you still don't need to bind in that context because it's expecting an expression. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick. If you've changed angular's binding syntax you probably should have chosen something that didn't already have a meaning in javascript. My question still stands though, did you try my suggestion?

Comment: If you see my HTML output, you can see that my binding is working well!
yes i tried

Comment: TWIG is a PHP template engine wich uses `{{ }}` to bind variables into template

Comment: So is your "rendered" HTML rendered by PHP or "rendered" by angular? Why don't you create a plunkr example using your replaced binding syntax so that there's no confusion with TWIG?

Comment: Also, no need to get shouty in your question, I'm trying to help you.

Comment: Sorry if I loose you ;) 
Actually there is no twig here, only angular, I have edited the first post so i hope it is more precise.

Comment: I'm afraid to say that it's because of those square brackets and I've proved it here. http://plnkr.co/edit/4n2yg6QudzcFA5bazjZ3?p=preview

Comment: OK, there is something that I don't understand but, you're right maybe it is brackets.

But why my function getFolder([id]) is working ... 

Thank you for helping, I will try something else.
Good Evening ! 
Fabien PAPET

Comment: There's no maybe about it, I'm definitely right. I suspect your other function isn't working as you think it is. Good evening to you, Fabien PAPET!